# What is the correct Universal Windows Platform OAuth Redirect URI?

Tags: javascript, oauth, uwp

I'm pretty green when it comes to programming so please, forgive me in advance.

The app I am writing is JavaScript UWP for Windows. I am trying to use Azure AD to authenticate the user and I'm using Web Authentication Broker for this.

When I run the app, it largely does what I want. It prompts the user for their Azure AD login, if the user hasn't granted the app permissions, they are requested, and all good. The problem is that the Web Authentication Broker pop-up never disappears. It stays on the screen like it's waiting for something.

I have a feeling that this is related to the callback URI and it is not receiving a response that it expects. I've read various Microsoft articles, GitHub projects, and Stack Overflow threads which all seem to disagree over what the callback URI should be.

Should it be the generic URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient, should it be ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/APPID, or should it be ms-appx://APPID?

The app I am writing is based on the GitHub sample https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAuthenticationBroker/js.

I have enabled the WebAuth Operational Event Log and I can see an Event ID 1011 Navigation Complete logged which shows that login.microsoftonline.com has responded with an access token, however, the UWP app does not see this.

UPDATED: Code and image added below.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var aadTenantId = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
var aadClientId = 'yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyy'
var microsoftGraphScopes = [
        "email",
        "openid",
        "offline_access",
        "Calendars.Read"
    ]
microsoftGraphScopes = microsoftGraphScopes.join('%20');

var redirectURL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient';
var redirectURLEncoded = encodeURIComponent(redirectURL);

var aadEndpointURL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + aadTenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=' + aadClientId + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURLEncoded + '&scope=' + microsoftGraphScopes + '&response_type=token';

var webAuthenticationBroker = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker;
var webAuthenticationOptions = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationOptions;
var webAuthenticationStatus = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationStatus;

var aadEndpointURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(aadEndpointURL);
var redirectURI = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(redirectURL);

webAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(webAuthenticationOptions.none, aadEndpointURI, redirectURI)
```

[image: Connecting to a service white screen and hung]

Comment: Actually the redirect URI should follow the rule listed [here] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) There are two parts, first, It must exactly match one of the redirect_uris you registered in the portal, second, it must be url encoded. So just type https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient is already OK for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, Barry. The redirect URI you state is the one I am currently using as I had read the link you provided before. My Azure AD Registered App is configured as Native and that URI is configured as a Redirect URI on the Native App.

I've updated the original post with the relevant section of code to show what I am doning to construct the request URL and the Web Authentication Broker connection. I've also posted a picture showing what the result is. The white screen in the image hangs there indefinitely.

Comment: Re-reading the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow it mentions that you need to get an authorization code first and with that, then request the token in a second request.

This is not shown in any of the GitHub examples: the examples do directly to requesting the access_token.

Comment: The webAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync method has a return value. Please use the return value to understand whether it returns success or fail result first(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.authenticateasync#Windows_Security_Authentication_Web_WebAuthenticationBroker_AuthenticateAsync_Windows_Security_Authentication_Web_WebAuthenticationOptions_Windows_Foundation_Uri_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barry Wang - MSFT was correct. After re-reading the documentation, I found that the I was trying to use the Token Flow which bypassess the Auth phase. It looks like that is only valid for certain use-cases so I switched over to the Auth Flow and it's all good.

Thanks Barry.